# Regex to Match lines with a Curly Brace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex that will basically go through a string and extract certain groups that I will use later.

I have a sample string that I am using:

```
foo bar baz

foo {
    bar
    baz
} asdf

a {
    b
    c
} d
```

And I want the output matches to be:

1. `foo bar baz`
2. Next:

   ```
   foo {
       bar
       baz
   } asdf
   ```
3. Finally:

   ```
   a {
       b
       c
   } d
   ```

   So the regex I have been working on is: `/(^[\s\S]+?\}|\S.+)\n?/g`
   But that still doesn't work. Can help with a regex or suggest maybe a better way to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to write an interpreter or compiler kinda thing. Whether or not, this is more or less similar to how parsers work. I doubt if any kind of Regex could do this. Either way, regex is not meant to solve things like this. [Take a look at PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/)

Comment: is `} foo` a closer to foo? In other words, if I had `PieCake {`, can I rely on `} PieCake` being there? Please reply with `@cfqueryparam` so that it notifies me. @vihan1086

Comment: @cfqueryparam I'm not necessarily relying on it. My point is I want to select the whole line with { and keep on matching every line until }. That said, I still do want to select the line with } .Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>try this pattern</s>

```
([^{\r\n]+{[^}]+}.*|.+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/204)

---

Per comment below you could use this pattern

```
([^{}\r\n]*{[^{}]*}[^{}\r\n]*|.+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/209)

---

new pattern

```
((?:[^{}\r\n]*{[^{}]*}[^{}\r\n]*)+|.+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/210)

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing but something more like: http://pastebin.com/JBidQ7qP thanks for the help so far. @alphabravo

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the best regex for this task, is simply `.*` (in javascript, `.` does not match newlines, so `.*` basically means the whole line.), and to evaluate the contents line by line. Regex can have a great amount of trouble with nested matches and parsing them out.

Something like this may work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qfLs7s01/3/. It is a line-by-line very rudimentary parser.

```
var funks = {} // this is an object to hold all the parsed out data
var funkname;
var nest = [];
var content = document.getElementById('container').value;
var cgather = content.replace(/(.*)/igm,function(match, p1) {
    p1 = p1.trim();
    if (p1.substr(p1.length-1,1) == "{") {
        funks[p1] = [];
        funkname = p1;
        nest.push(p1);
    } else if (p1.substr(0,1) == "}") {
        if (nest.length > 0) {
            funkname = nest[nest.length-2];
            nest.splice(-1,1);
        } else {
            nest = [];
        }
    } else {
        if (p1.length) funks[funkname].push(p1)
    }
    return p1;
})

console.log(funks);
```

The only trouble is how this handles duplicate function names.

```
foo {
  foo content
} foo

bar {
  bar content
} bar

foo {
  more foo content
}
```

will result in a struct of arrays like `{foo: ["foo content","more foo content"], bar: ["bar content"]}`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did a few changes to deal with duplicate function names

Comment: @vihan1086 Interesting, mind sharing in a comment with a jsFiddle?